# Jupyter notebook inside PyCharm refuses to see an env var?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, environment-variables

I have exported the env var:

`export kuku=bubu`

I am using pipenv and pyenv in my pycharm.

Now when I am going to the notebook and asking `os.getenv("kuku")` I am getting `None`.

What can be the reason and how to fix it?

Comment: How do you start the notebook? You need to start the Jupyter server or kernel from the same shell where you are setting the environment variable.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I have opened a ipynb file - the jupyter notebook and just run the cells. For some reason it doesn't see any env var I have configured.

Comment: Environment variables are only effective in the child processes of the shell where you set them. Is your Jupyter Notebook a child process for this shell?

Comment: How can I check it? It says it is managed on localhost and uses the right interpreter (same as the pipenv env) @MikkoOhtamaa

Comment: I assume you did not launch PyCharm from the shell where you set the environment variable, so I do not know how any PyCharm managed process would have inherited this environment variable. You can launch the Jupyter kernel in a shell where you set the environment variable and then use PyCharm remote kernel feature to connect to it and I think this should solve your issue.